# Discord.js How to know that user are in voice chat or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My problem is I want to make my bot check that users are in voice chat or not on line 8 but I don't know how to check
and how do I get that voice chat ID that users are in?

What should I use or do?

Here is my code

```
if (CMD_NAME === 'poke' && msg.channel.type != 'dm') {
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(msg.author.lastMessageChannelID);
    msg.delete();
    if (args[0] != null) {
        var Target = msg.guild.member(msg.mentions.users.first() || msg.guild.members.fetch(args[0]))
        var GuildMember = msg.guild.members.cache.get(Target.user.id)

        if (Target && GuildMember && msg.member.voice.channel != null && // Check that users are in voice chat //) {
            var MainChannel = // The ID of voice chat that users are in //
            var ChannelID = []
            var server = msg.guild;
            var i = 0
                    
            if (args[1] == null) {
                args[1] = 5
            }
                    
            var Time = args[1]
    
            for (const channel of server.channels.cache.array()) {
                if (channel.type == 'voice' && channel.id != MainChannel) {
                    ChannelID.push(channel.id);
                }
                    
            }
    
            if (Time > 5) {
                Time = 5
            }
    
            function Move() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    if (GuildMember != null && MainChannel != null) {
                        GuildMember.voice.setChannel(ChannelID[getRandomInt(0, ChannelID.length)])
                        i++;
                        if (i <= Time) {
                            Move()
                        } else if (i > Time && GuildMember != null && MainChannel != null) {
                            GuildMember.voice.setChannel(MainChannel)
                        }
                    }
                }, 900)
            }
                    
            Move();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GuildMember`s have a `voice` property (see [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=voice)) which returns an instance of [`VoiceState`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/VoiceState).  VoiceState.channel will return null if the member isn’t connected to voice

```js
//member is an instance of GuildMember
if(!member.voice.channel) {
//member not connected to voice
}
```

To check who is in a specific voice channel, use [`VoiceChannel.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=members)

```js
//vchannel is an instance of VoiceChannel
const { members } = vchannel
//members is now a collection of members in the vc
```