# Bot doesn't detect if the user is in a voice channel! || Discord.JS V.14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This is my code:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { createAudioPlayer, createAudioResource, joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('play')
    .setDescription('Play a song in your current voice channel')
    .addStringOption(option =>
      option.setName('song')
        .setDescription('Enter the YouTube URL or keywords to search for')
        .setRequired(true)),
  async execute(interaction) {
    const song = interaction.options.getString('song');

    // Check if the user is in a voice channel
    if (!interaction.member.voice.channel) {
      return interaction.reply({ content: 'You are not in a voice channel!', ephemeral: true });
    }

    // Join the user's voice channel
    const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
      channelId: interaction.member.voice.channel.id,
      guildId: interaction.guildId,
      adapterCreator: interaction.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
    });

    // Get video info and create an audio resource
    const videoInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(song);
    const stream = ytdl(song, { filter: 'audioonly' });
    const resource = createAudioResource(stream);

    // Create an audio player and play the resource
    const player = createAudioPlayer();
    player.play(resource);

    // Subscribe the connection to the player
    connection.subscribe(player);

    // Send a confirmation message
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor("Green")
      .setTitle('Now Playing')
      .setDescription(`[${videoInfo.videoDetails.title}](${song})`)
      .setThumbnail(videoInfo.videoDetails.thumbnails[0].url);
    interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
  },
};
```

Play.js - This is a command that lets users play music in the voice channel they are in. The user must be on a voice channel, run the command and then the bot will connect to the same channel as the user. The problem is that when I'm on the voice channel it also sends the `'You are not in a voice channel!'` and doesn't proceed to the next step! I believe that the problem is located here:

```js
if (!interaction.member.voice.channel) {
      return interaction.reply({ content: 'You are not in a voice channel!', ephemeral: true });
    }
```

Could anyone please help me with this issue (If you spot any other issues, it would be great to let me know as well.). Thanks in advance!

I have the following intents: `[Guilds, GuildMembers, GuildMessages, MessageContent, DirectMessages]`.

### NOTE:

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68684637/discord-js-how-to-know-that-user-are-in-voice-chat-or-not) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69294590/issue-with-discord-js-voice-player) does NOT solve my case and it is NOT a duplicate.

Comment: What intents have you enabled?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros  I have enabled all the following intents:
`[Guilds, GuildMembers, GuildMessages, MessageContent, DirectMessages]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll also need to add the `GuildVoiceStates` intent to see voice state changes. Without that `interaction.member.voice` will always return a "snapshot" of the voice state when you started your bot.

Without the `GuildVoiceStates` intent changes are not detected; if the member is already connected when you start your bot, `interaction.member.voice` will return the voice state correctly, but if they're disconnected and you check it again, the value is the same so it seems they're still in that voice channel.